# Replace String In Object Property Value After Looping Array Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I'm needing to replace a character in an object's property value. I'm looping over the array of objects (outputting to console) and retrieving the FeatureUrl property.

I have data coming back from the Svc for that property in the following form:

index.html#/blah

I'm needing to replace the '#' with '#/app' so that my new url comes back in the following form:

index.html#/app/blah

I'm not sure if .replace is the right method to use here, but it is what I have seen suggested. Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
var localFeatureDetails = function() {
    $scope.user = userService.GetUserInformation();
    $scope.featureDetails = $scope.user.Features;

  var featureUrlRewrite = function () {
    var index;
    var urlCount;
    for (index = 0; index < $scope.featureDetails.length; index++) {
      urlCount = $scope.featureDetails[index];
      urlCount.FeatureUrl.replace("#","#/app");
      console.log(urlCount);
    }
  };

  featureUrlRewrite();

};
localFeatureDetails();
```

Comment: Does this work?  Are you asking for confirmation?  If that's the case I recommend using http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: if the code works the way you intend it to, then it may be a good fit on CR.  Does this code work?

Comment: Replace at takes the location in the string, the OP is looking for a specific character in the string and replacing it with a set of characters. `replaceAt` is not the right tool here. the location in the string array may change based on the page

Comment: +1, this is not a duplicate of the suggested question. `replaceAt` would *not* work here, OP appears to want a mutable version of `replace`. Unfortunately, strings are immutable so no such method exists. The suggested answer seems to do what you would want.

Comment: The code loops and returns the index(s) of the array and the property that I need, but the .replace() method is not replacing the characters that I need it to. It is coming back unchanged.

Comment: @billy_comic that's because `replace` is immutable and returns a new instance of the modified string instead of modifying the string in-place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not test your code but based on how `.replace()` works you have to assign the value to your object property again by overriding it otherwise you're not saving the value.

Assuming everything else is correct, try this:
`$scope.featureDetails[index].FeatureUrl = urlCount.FeatureUrl.replace("#","#/app");`

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: @dc hayka this worked perfectly. I altered just a tad, but great solution.

Comment: @billy_comic awesome, glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

I think that you might want something more like this

```
$scope.featureDetails.map(detail => angular.merge({}, detail, 
    { FeatureUrl: detail.replace('#', '#/app') }))
```

instead of the bulky for loop.

we take every `detail` object out of the `featureDetails` array, access the `FeatureUrl` property and replace the `#` with `#/app`

*`.merge(destination, ...sources)`* merges ***sources*** into ***destination***, left-to-right, overwriting properties as it goes.

so `angular.merge({}, {foo: 5, bar: 3}, {foo: 7})` would return `{ foo: 7, bar: 3 }`

Removed the `console.log()` but you can always

```
console.log($scope.featureDetails);
```

and then look at the object that is returned in the inspector.

Comment: I'm going to try this as anytime I can avoid a loop, i'm down. Thx for the suggestion.